# setListAdapter not working for fragment? any alternatives

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, fragment, listadapter

```
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */


                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        getActivity(), inboxList,
                        R.layout.inbox_list_item, new String[] { TAG_LINK, TAG_SUBJECT },
                        new int[] { R.id.link, R.id.subject });
                // updating listview
                lv.setListAdapter(adapter);

                            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), 
                                "You clicked on feed "+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                    }

                });

            }
        });

    }
```

Im trying to get a list view in a fragment activity. 
This list view is a parsed from JSON objects.
This code runs in a fragment. However, setlistadapter gives an error. Any alternatives for setlistadapter and how to implement it.
Thank you.

Comment: Instead of extending Fragment, extend ListFragment.

Comment: our application has several fragments and this is one of them. These fragments are displayed in tabs of the navigation drawer and my code is needs all the activities to be a fragment(but not listFragment).
So I need setlistadapter in the fragment.

Comment: Ok..then its a complete different scenario. Please tell me what error does exactly occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Custom adapter Like this:

```
Listview list = (Listview)findviewbyId(R.id.list);
SearchListAdapter adapter = new SearchListAdapter(this,
                        getActivity(), rowItems(your data to inflate in adapter));
                lis.setAdapter(adapter);
```